# Django: Uploading an XML file from HTML page

Tags: python, html, xml, django

I am using Django framework and python scripts for validating XML files.

I usually parse the XML file, which is already present in the defined location, using the below code.

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
tree = ET.parse('config.xml')
```

However, now I want to add the file dynamically from the front end browse file option and place it in the above ET.parse('file.xml') location. What is the best way to achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<form action="/handle_xml_upload/" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <input type="file" name="xmlfile">

    <input type="submit" value="upload xml file">
</form>
```

and in views.py

```
def handle_xml_upload(request):
    xmlfile = request.FILES['xmlfile']
    tree = ET.parse(xmlfile)
    # ...
```

of course, you need adjust your urls.py as well ;)